# Can't install composer with docker on Google Cloud platform - Getting error Could not open input file: artisan

Tags: php, laravel, docker, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to build laravel project with docker on Google cloud platform. I am getting `Could not open input file: artisan` error in Google logs. I have tried all solutions out there, unfortunately none of them is working :(

Here is my DockerFile

```
FROM php:8.1

ENV PORT 8080

RUN apt update
RUN apt install wget
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y zip
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN apt-get install -y curl

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --2

WORKDIR /app

COPY composer.json .

RUN composer install

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    npm
RUN npm install npm@latest -g && \
    npm install n -g && \
    n latest

COPY . .

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port 8080
```

After building it using docker command locally, I get this error `Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1` in the terminal.

[image]

Also, I have the artisan file in my root project folder.

[image]

I have exactly the same variables in Google Cloud platform variables as well. My .env file is below.

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:+ly4U3QbWcULnj0A31g41q7Yim/L0W5olgwPbsuD1/A=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8080

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=test
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testdb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Please tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first `COPY . .` and then run `composer install`...

I do not recommend to have `CMD php artisan serve` as your image driver... just have another container like NGINX or Apache...

I also do not recommend installing and doing stuff in the image creation... running `composer install` is not part of an image, and if it is, you have to be very careful, as if the composer part fails, you have no image to do something with php...

---

Why do you have to `COPY . .` before `composer install`? Because you have nothing on the image being built, you only have `composer.json` so `composer install` works, but when it has to run composer's post install commands, you have nothing else, that is why you have to move EVERYTHING into the image, then install

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. It works!! 
Can you show how to create this NGINX container as well and what should I put in? I am new to docker and confused.

Comment: @za_ali33 No worries, you should be able to use [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail). Depending on what PHP version you want, you can have a look at the [official repository](https://github.com/laravel/sail/tree/1.x/runtimes)

Comment: alright will check ✌